# Android cross compilation

Tags: android

How can I use Nmap port scanner on Android SDK in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you meant, so here are the answers to some of the possible meanings:

Installing nmap on windows:
http://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html#inst-win-source

Running nmap on an android device:
http://www.helloandroid.com/ideas/nmap

To run an nmap scan against an android device, I assume you need to have it on a wifi network and know it's IP address. In which case, just run the scan as you normally would.